# spring boot javafx load video from resource folder

Tags: javafx, spring-boot

Hi i have a spring boot javafx app. I want to load video from `resources/video/a.mp4` .

```
final Media m = new Media(getClass().getResource("/video/a.mp4").toString());
        this.player = new MediaPlayer(m);
        final MediaView view = new MediaView(player);
        final DoubleProperty width = view.fitWidthProperty();
        final DoubleProperty height = view.fitHeightProperty();
        width.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(view.sceneProperty(), "width"));
        height.bind(Bindings.selectDouble(view.sceneProperty(), "height"));
        view.setPreserveRatio(true);
        mainlayout.getChildren().add(view);
        player.play();
```

The code above not playing video. Always showing nullpointer exception.

Comment: Can you show the structure of your build/output folder or jar file? Is the mp4 file in the expected location in the generated build?

Comment: its not about making jar file.it is not playing on runtime

Comment: It needs to read the mp4 file at runtime. So if it is running from a jar file, the mp4 file needs to be in the jar file. If it is running from the file system, it needs to be in the build/output folder along with the class files. Either way, can you show the appropriate runtime structure, i.e. where the mp4 file is relative to the classpath. (The resources folder is (typically) a source folder, which obviously isn't relevant when looking for something at runtime.)

Comment: Thanks for your advice